# How does the EncryptFile function work and why can I still the contents?

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption

I am using the [`EncryptFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to encrypt files and directories but I get as result, the same file or folder with a green text name.

Am I missing something? Where is the encrypted data?

```
BOOL res= EncryptFile( L"D:\\test");
qDebug()<<"res "<<res<<"  last error  "<<GetLastError();
```

Comment: If your system doesn't have a Guest account, create it now. Try to open your file using the Guest account. That will fail since it's encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses Windows *[Encrypted File System](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/What-is-Encrypting-File-System-EFS)* that uses your user's login details as encryption keys.

The encryption is transparent and when the current *Windows Principal* opens a file, his/her security details are used to unencrypt its contents.

Comment: so if I try to decrypt my file with other computer or by accessing with different user I couldn't?

Comment: @oumaya If by another computer, it's accessing it if this one with a different username, then yes. If you copy the file to another machine, the encryption is lost.

Comment: so all is tied to user name and login information, that's right? I want that even with my login information it still unreadable (cipher text) unless I decrypt it with the correct password, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but this happens behind the scenes in Windows and all you need to do is get a principal set. So it would work with Kerberos authentication, too.

Comment: @oumaya Then you'll need to use some other file encryption utility.

Comment: @Henrik what do you mean by get a principal set please .

Comment: @Deanna my application implements already an encryption algorithm but I thought to use `EncryptFile function` to create an encrypted folder so any file within will be automatically encrypted and I will not have to encrypt it file by file by my self, so is there any way to integrate my algorithm to work with the encrypted folder. Any idea please !!!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing something. The green text name means windows has encrypted it.

Comment: But thats probably because YOU encrypted it, if you log in as another user, is it still readable?

Comment: I tried to email the encrypted folder and open it in an other machine it's not cipher !!!. I can not found out what the purpose of encryption , is it save data from only other users of my computer?

Comment: Ah, but you told it to open it and send it - try as I asked, logged in as another user.. It shouldnt open it then.

Comment: I'am not allowed to create another user but I can trust you and assume that  `EncryptFile function ` is useful only if I want to protect my data from other users of my computer, is that correct?

Comment: Yes.. As you are allowed to open it, the file its self is then duplicated content wise to other apps, so all the apps you use can read it.